# Тотальная безграмотность

Tags: общие-вопросы

Я вот все думаю: почему сейчас среди людей, особенно следи молодежи такая катастрофическая безграмотность? Что изменилось? Почитать интернет — это же кромешный ужас какой-то. Старшеклассники и студенты не знают ЭЛЕМЕНТАРНЕЙШИХ правил. Более того, чуть ли не гордятся этим и агрессивно реагируют на замечания.
А сколько ошибок во всевозможных вывесках и ценниках. Недавно мне попался красиво оформленный, напечатанный в типографии ценник мороженого с "гриб фруктом".
Или раньше, когда не было интернета, эта безграмотность была не так заметна?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мой взгляд раньше народ был чутка пограмотнее, хотя и не так чтобы уж очень. 
Сейчас просто перестали вообще задумываться над необходимостью следовать орфографии и пунктуцации.  Правда для этого иногда бывают довольно веские причины (по себе знаю). 
Но валить все на интернет я бы не стал. Жизнь поменялась, все в бегах, у всех проблемы... До жы-шы ли тут?

Хотя иногда это еще и провление этакого нигилизма, а такой вот я крутой перец, не ботан какой-нить, которому правила надо знать. Я не об олбанском, это отдельная статья, но про него уже почти все сказано.

Answer (score 1):

А мне кажется, что уже немодно быть безграмотным. Я обратила внимание, что в интернете 15-летние мальчишки пишут не только орфографически грамотно, но (что меня поразило больше всего) ставят точки в конце предложений и пишут их с заглавной буквы, правильно расставляют запятые в своих сообщениях в чатах. "Приведов" я последнее время совсем не вижу, как и многих других нарочно коверкаемых слов. А безграмотные школьники были всегда. Не думаю, что их процент в последние годы вырос.

Answer (score 0):

"Агрессивно" и "нигилизм" - ключевые слова. Разруха в головах, эпоха перемен. Разнобой в орфографии всегда усиливается в такие эпохи. Но эта эпоха, похоже, заканчивается.

Компьютер оказывает на правописание двойное действие: с одной стороны, помогает писать правильно (вот я промахнулся - "правлиьно" - и браузер подчеркнул мне слово красным), а с другой - способствует тому, чтобы люди "перестали задумываться" над правилами письма, понимать их природу.

Comment: grumant, мне не нравится Ваша манера говорить не по теме.

Answer (score 0):

О каких бегах вы говорите, если часами и днями "банитесь" в интернете. Вся зта крутость и нмгилизм - отговорки в пользу бедных (бескультурных), чтобы скрыть свою безграмотность. Это легко проверить: продиктуйте такому нигилисту(хотя бы на спор) проблемное предложение и он сделает по 3 ошибки в слове, не говоря о пунктуации.

Comment: Хотелось бы повежливее и попонятнее